# How to disable accessibility font bolding in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I can detect if fonts are bold because of accessibility in iOS, using **UIAccessibilityIsBoldTextEnabled**, but I can't disable font bolding in my app.

Is there any way so I can keep my app from bolding, because my texts are already bold and accessibility will make them even **bolder**!

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: Anybody have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that work only if the user has enabled Bold Text in the settings, else, why would you want to go against the User Preference?

Else, you can try overriding the setting using this:

```
AnyUIView.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "yourFont", size: yourSize)
```

Hope this helps.